# Rails CSS zebra-striping rows, but in sets of three

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, cycle

**What I know:**
Rails has the `cycle()` method that enables odd/even rows in a table to have different CSS classes. We can pass multiple classes to the `cycle()` method and that works great.

I wanted rows which are grouped in three's; so, I used this:

```
...some html-table  code...
<tr class="<%= cycle("table_row_1","table_row_2","table_row_3","table_row_4","table_row_5","table_row_6") %>">
...some more html-table  code...
```

The corresponding CSS I defined is:

```
.table_row_1 { background-color: red;}
.table_row_2 { background-color: red;}
.table_row_3 { background-color: red;}
.table_row_4 { background-color: blue;}
.table_row_5 { background-color: blue;}
.table_row_6 { background-color: blue;}
```

It works, but it doesn't feel "clean".

Is there a recommended way to do this in Rails ?

**UPDATES**

1. On similar lines to @Ryan Bigg's answer, is it possible to generate strings in sequence so that the cycle() method can be sent strings of the form `prefix_1 prefix_2 prefix_3` somehow using the `*3` syntax or some other way?
2. The inspiration to use this "every third row" striping came from an [article on Edward Tufte's site](http://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=0001IV&topic_id=1&topic=Ask+E.T.)
3. It seems CSS3 can do this ([link](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/stylesheets/advancedselectors.html)), but that's not widely supported at this time :(
4. Not related to question, but I just searched for this problem I have on Google, and the questions listed at [questionhub.com](http://www.questionhub.com/StackOverflow/3844493)! I never asked this on questionhub.com!
5. Now its on [http://loopingrecursion.com](http://loopingrecursion.com/?t=css) too! What's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
<tr class="<%= cycle(*[["striped"]*3,["unstriped"]*3].flatten) %>">
```

Comment: After adding a space after the "striped", it still doesn't work -- I get for row 1: `<tr class="striped striped striped ">` and row 2:`<tr class="unstriped unstriped unstriped ">` and the process repeats, thus getting the even/odd effect.

Comment: @Zabba: Updated answer to use splat operator and flatten. This will work now.

Comment: @QueueHammer, the code above translates to the call `cycle("striped", "striped", "striped", "unstriped", "unstriped", "unstriped")`. [See here for how cycle() works](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle).

Answer (score 2):

Actually this sounds like something i would solve using pure CSS:

```
table tr:nth-child(6n+1), table tr:nth-child(6n+2), table tr:nth-child(6n+3) { background:red;} 
table tr:nth-child(6n+4), table tr:nth-child(6n+5), table tr:nth-child(6n)   { background:blue;}
```

While this is short and dandy, this [does not work in IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx) unfortunately (it will work in the new IE9).

To get this working you could use jQuery, which offers the same selectors and is completely cross-browser compatible.

In your css you add two classes:

```
table_row_third_even { background: red;}
table_row_third_odd { background: blue;}
```

and then you write some javascript (inside `application.js` for instance), like this

```
$(function() {
  $('table tr:nth-child(6n+1), table tr:nth-child(6n+2), table tr:nth-child(6n+3)').addClass('table_row_third_even');
  $('table tr:nth-child(6n+4), table tr:nth-child(6n+5), table tr:nth-child(6n)').addClass('table_row_third_odd');
});
```

and your table would have to have the class `highlight` (you should change that to a better suiting name, this is just an example); but nothing specific for your `tr` tags, as they will be added by the javascript code.

```
<table class='highlight'>
  <tr> ... </tr>
  <tr> ... </tr>
  <tr> ... </tr>
  <tr> ... </tr>
</table>
```

But for this to work you would need to introduce jQuery inside your project. The good thing: it would keep your ruby-code clear from the clutter needed to do this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good to note that there is no IE support for this. Not even IE 8.

Comment: Really? Bummmmmmmer. One could always consider jquery to the rescue :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this, which is sort of "clean" and suits me for now. Details:

In a controller helper (no error checking, yet!):

```
def cycle_every_third(options = [])
  cycle(options[0],options[0],options[0],options[1],options[1],options[1])
end
```

HTML:

```
...
<tr class="<%= cycle_every_third(["table_row_1","table_row_2"] ) %>">
...
```

CSS:

```
.table_row_1 {   background-color: red;}
.table_row_2 {   background-color: blue;}
```

Is that a good way to go about this I wonder? Any pitfalls in Rails I may not be aware of, of calling `cycle()` inside a helper method as opposed to calling it in the rhtml/erb file?

Comment: This would definitely work, and no real arguments against it. I would prefer to use the suggestion from @Ryan_Bigg, as i find that more compact and clearer (i find `*3` easier to understand than a row of items ... but i guess that is subjective).